# Execute multiple instances of same SSIS package at same time

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis-2008

I want to execute a SSIS package multiple times through SQL Server Job and each time it executes it should store the data in different table if the package is already running.

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but it is definitely possible and there are many ways of doing it. Please expand a bit more on what you've done so far and where have you've got stuck.

Comment: I have a SSIS Package which takes Data from a source table , processes it and then stores it in a destination table. I want to make both source and destination tables dynamic i.e. if this package is running and using source1 and destination1 tables then on parallel execution of the same package using a SQL Job it should use Source2 and Destination2 tables and so on. In short I have multiple sources of data which should be processed simultaneously using a single SSIS package.